# In extensions, make the schema update SQL conditional

Tags: component, joomla-4.x, sql, extension-update, versions

In the xml install file for an extension for Joomla! 4.0, there are these lines that make the SQL update :

```
<update>
    <schemas>
        <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates/mysql</schemapath>
    </schemas>
</update>
```

The installation package is tagged as 6.0.0-RC1-DEV for developpement. In the directory sql/updates/mysql, I have two files: 6.0.0-BETA1-DEV.sql and 6.0.0-RC1-DEV.sql.

When i install the package 6.0.0-RC1-DEV in Joomla! which have already installed 6.0.0-BETA7-DEV version, the files 6.0.0-BETA1-DEV.sql and 6.0.0-RC1-DEV.sql are executed, but i want only in this case that 6.0.0-RC1-DEV.sql be executed

In the file  6.0.0-BETA1-DEV.sql there are ALTER TABLE queries, by example :

```
ALTER TABLE `#__mycomponent_cats` CHANGE `allow_anonym` `allowAnonym` tinyint DEFAULT NULL;
```

I have found a way which works only in mariadb by not in mysql :

```
ALTER TABLE `#__mycomponent_cats` CHANGE COLUMN IF EXISTS `allow_anonym` `allowAnonym` tinyint DEFAULT NULL;
```

To avoid that query fails it should check that eh column allow_anonym exist before

How can the execution of the sql file be made conditional?

Comment: Are there specific indicators in db tables that you can use to indicate that a particular table should or should not be altered?  Something like if a table exists? Or if a column in a table exists? If so, can you bake the conditional check directly into your sql file?  Do we need more context to understand your scenario?

Comment: I have edited my message above, i hope it's more clear for the issue and on what i want to achieve